# How to access an EKCalendar's `account` property

Tags: objective-c, eventkit

Take a look at [the documentation for EKCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Reference/EKCalendarClassRef/Reference/Reference.html). It's pretty simple, it has five properties, only one of which is a string called `title`. Now if you have multiple calendars on your iPhone and you open iCal's Calendar settings, you can see that all calendars are nicely grouped by another string called `account`.

What I can't figure out, is how to do the same, because although you can see the `account` when you `NSLog` a `EKCalendar` instance, you can't access it:

> EKCalendar <0x1851b0> {title = Work; type = CalDAV; account = some@addr.ess; allowsModify = YES; color = 0.690196 0.152941 0.682353 1.000000}

There is no `account` property, and trying to access the `valueForKey:@"account"` isn't working either, unsurprisingly.

So how do I get to that `account` property? Such a simple thing, driving me nuts! Help is much appreciated.

**Update:** since iOS 5.0, [EKCalendar has a `source` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Reference/EKCalendarClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKCalendar/source).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) on the iOS 4.3 (Simulator) SDK, you'll see that there's a read-only method `-(id)accountName`. However, since it's not in the headers, it's unfortunately private API and you can't use it if you want your App to be accepted in the App Store.

I recommend that you [file an enhancement request with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) requesting that this method be made public.

Though thinking about it: If you're really desperate, why not parse the output of `-[EKCalendar description]`? It's very very very bad style and it'll probably break in the future, but you might make it through the App Store review ;) In particular if you only use it for grouping and write your code extremely defensive so it doesn't break but simply doesn't group, should the output of the `description` method be formatted differently.

Comment: Hacky as it is, your suggestion of parsing EKCalendar description is actually pretty nifty, I hadn't thought of that myself. And the class-dump utility is a great bonus, thanks! If it weren't for the hint @DaveDeLong gave me to look into future iOS reference, I would actually invest the time into it. Now I'll just work on other parts of the app till fall. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This information is not available in the 4.0 SDK.  Have you looked at the developer previews of the forthcoming SDK to see if that might contain more information?

Comment: I have now, and it turned out to be a very good idea. There's something coming up in iOS 5 that will take away the pain in selecting calendars. Thanks for the nudge! Added to my #WWDDLD list: Check future iOS reference :)

Answer (score 1):

And on iOS6? It seems the private property `[EKCalendar accountName]` vanished. And `[EKCalendar description]` does not contain account anymore. :

> EKCalendar <0x200f50e0> {title = test@gmail.com; type = Exchange; allowsModify = YES; color = #44A703;}

The `[EKCalendar source]` provides a `EKSource` object, that has a title but this is not the name I typed when I created the account but seems to be a more generic name, e.g. Exchange, Other, CalDAV.