# Access iPhones calendar events

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, calendar

In my Iphone Application, I want to check the built in Calendar App for upcoming Events.

The aim would be to for example mute the app, when the user is supposed to be in a meeting.

I couldn't find anything on that matter though, as search results only present a way to implement your own calendar

So is it possible to get this acces ( and is there maybe a short example or link that i couldnt find) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cant mute the iPhone

As the physical hardware switch is available, there's no software method for muting the entire device.

You don't need to fight with the framework, until he/she wants to mute it.

and if you want to check the upcoming events, you need to go through the [Event store](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) and [EKCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Reference/EKCalendarClassRef/Reference/Reference.html).

and i guess you cant access the users events in your app with out his permission as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6417759/1278036) answer says

and there is a [Simple EK Demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160) from apple, which may help you..

Cheers...

Comment: yes this helps a lot thx

I didn't want to mute the whole phone, but for example automaticaly deactivate sounds of a game during a meeting.